# Getting a blob size without the blob itself

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, blob

I have a table that has a blob column representing a file.
I'd like to run a LinqToSql query that returns a name and description of the file, along with the file size... but in the interests of not killing performance, I obviously don't want to download the whole blob!

```
var q = from f in MyFiles
        select new {f.Name, f.Description, f.Blob.Length};
```

appears to pull the entire blob from the DB, then calculate its length in local memory.

How can I do this so that I only get the blob size, without downloading the entire blob?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best choose in your case is to  store blob size in the separate column, when storing file to database.

Comment: +1 - This is exactly what I would do, but I would hope there was a better way of doing this

Comment: +1 +answer credit - yeah, not very graceful, but very little performance penalty.  Just added a computed column and it works fine!